# How can I solve my error below with a query?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

When running this code:

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> AddMessage()
    {
        int distid = ViewBag.DISTRIBUTORID;
        ViewBag.PageName = "Send Message";

        int id = Convert.ToByte(ViewBag.ID);
        ViewBag.UserId = id;

        var messages = await _companyContext.MESAJLAR.Where(p => p.SENDERID == id || p.SENTID == id).OrderBy(p => p.DATE).GroupBy(p => p.SPECIALID).Select(p => p.Last()).ToListAsync();
        var ids1 = messages.Select(p => p.SENDERID).ToArray();
        var ids2 = messages.Select(p => p.SENTID ).ToArray();

        var users= await _userDatabaseContext.user.Where(p => p.DISTID == distid && p.ID != id && !ids1.Contains(p.ID) && !ids2.Contains(p.ID)).ToListAsync();

        return View(new AddMessageViewModel
        {
            USERS= users
        });
    }
```

I get the following error:

> Queries performing 'Last' operation must have a deterministic sort order.Rewrite the query to apply an 'OrderBy' operation on the sequence before calling 'Last'.

I'm getting it at the line that starts with `var messages = ...`

Comment: *I get the error you see above* - **NO** we don't see - since you haven't posted anything .....

Comment: You did not order the groups on which you use the '.Last()' call. That is your error. Order the groups before calling 'last()' and it should work.

Comment: You need an order statement in here : `.Select(p => p.Last())` --> `.Select(p => p.OderBy(q=> q.DATE).Last())` That also make the previous `Order` statement redundant.

Comment: Hi @ismail temel, it is better for you to share the result you want. It means you need give a example about the database data and give the result you want after querying. Besides, Eldar's suggestion can make the error disappear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem with your query is, that you are trying to select `.Last()` without ordering your data first.
Right now you are ordering your data, then group it and after that you try to select 'Last()'.
You have to order the grouped data to use '.Last()'.

```
var messages = await _companyContext.MESAJLAR.Where(p => p.SENDERID == id || p.SENTID == id).OrderBy(p => p.DATE).GroupBy(p => p.SPECIALID).OrderBy(p => p.XXXXX).Select(p => p.Last()).ToListAsync();
```

And your first order would probably be not needed anymore.